# Repository doesn't save data to H2 in-memory db

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

Here is my controller method:

```
// CREATE A USER
@PostMapping("/register")
public String createUser(
        @RequestBody User user
) {
    if (userService.userExists(user)) {
        return "User already exists";
    }

    userService.saveUser(user);
    return "Good job!";
}
```

**UserServiceBean**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceBean {


private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public UserServiceBean(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

public User saveUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

public boolean userExists(User user) {
    if (userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And my interface repository:
**UserRepository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

// TODO: 29.01.17 Create a query to find all todos for logged in user

@Query("select td from User u inner join u.toDoItems td where u = :user")
public Iterable<ToDoItem> findAllToDosForLoggedInUser(@Param("user") User user);

public User findByUsername(String username);
```

}

And here is my **User Entity** (getters and setters ommited)

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "USERS")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String username;

// TODO: 28.01.17 Find a way to store hashed and salted pws in DB
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;

// user can have many ToDoItems
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<ToDoItem> toDoItems;

// JPA demands empty constructor
public User() {}

public User(String username, String password, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}
```

When I shoot JSON at my localhost:8080/register:

```
{
"username":"ss",
"password":"mkyong.com",
"email":"asdasd@wp.pl"
}
```

I get response *Good job!* so it works fine. But when I check my DB at localhost:8080/console it just has Test Table and new User is not added.

I've got my hibernate ddl setup in application.properties set:

```
# Console to H2 database to check data
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

So, how do I update my code that it creates table USERS and save created user into that db? I'm going to change my db later on, just using H2 to check if my controllers work fine but it shouldn't matter here.

EDIT:
Here is my **RepositoryConfiguration.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.doublemc.domain"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.doublemc.repositories"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RepositoryConfiguration {
}
```

EDIT2:
When I want to register the same User again (using same JSON) then it gives me "User already exists" resposne so it is already in the db... Why can't I see it then? Maybe I've got H2 somewhere else? Not in the basic /console or different port? How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the transactional part of your service. Did you define a transaction manager in your spring context ?

If so, you need to add the annotation `@Transactional` into your service. For example :

```
@Service
public class UserServiceBean {

    @Transactional
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Transaction manager isn't auto-configured when I'm using Spring Boot with CrudRepository interface? When I added Transactional as you mentioned it still didn't populate H2 db.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide your spring configuration please ?

Comment: Added, it's empty class with just annotations - read somewhere it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

to application.properties and it works great now. I just thought I don't need it becasue Spring will auto-configure it for me but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: If it is spring-boot 1.5+ then only URL is enough